# Creating fast RGB look up tables in Python

Tags: python, performance, numpy, opencv, lookup-tables

I have a function I will call 'rgb2something' that transforms RGB data [1x1x3] into a single value (a probability), looping over each pixel in the input RGB data turns out to be rather slow.

I have tried the following approach to speed the conversion up. To generate the LUT (Look up table):

```
import numpy as np

levels = 256
levels2 = levels**2
lut = [0] * (levels ** 3)

levels_range = range(0, levels)

for r in levels_range:
    for g in levels_range:
        for b in levels_range:
            lut[r + (g * levels) + (b * levels2)] = rgb2something(r, g, b)
```

And to convert RGB to the transformed probability image:

```
result = np.take(lut, r_channel + (g_channel * 256) + (b_channel * 65536))
```

However both generating the LUT and calculating the result is still slow. In 2 dimensions it's rather fast, however in 3 dimensions (r, g and b) it's slow. How can I increase the performance of this?

## EDIT

`rgb2something(r, g, b)` looks like this:

```
def rgb2something(r, g, b):
    y = np.array([[r, g, b]])
    y_mean = np.mean(y, axis=0)
    y_centered = y - y_mean
    y_cov = y_centered.T.dot(y_centered) / len(y_centered)
    m = len(Consts.x)
    n = len(y)
    q = m + n
    pool_cov = (m / q * x_cov) + (n / q * y_cov)
    inv_pool_cov = np.linalg.inv(pool_cov)
    g = Consts.x_mean - y_mean
    mah = g.T.dot(inv_pool_cov).dot(g) ** 0.5
    return mah
```

## EDIT 2:

Full working code sample of what I'm trying to achieve, I am using OpenCV so any OpenCV approaches such as [Apply LUT](https://www.learnopencv.com/tag/lut/) are welcome, as are C/C++ approaches:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np 
import cv2

class Model:
    x = np.array([
        [6, 5, 2],
        [2, 5, 7],
        [6, 3, 1]
    ])
    x_mean = np.mean(x, axis=0)
    x_centered = x - x_mean
    x_covariance = x_centered.T.dot(x_centered) / len(x_centered)
    m = len(x)
    n = 1  # Only ever comparing to a single pixel
    q = m + n
    pooled_covariance = (m / q * x_covariance)  # + (n / q * y_cov) -< Always 0 for a single point
    inverse_pooled_covariance = np.linalg.inv(pooled_covariance)

def rgb2something(r, g, b):
    #Calculates Mahalanobis Distance between pixel and model X
    y = np.array([[r, g, b]])
    y_mean = np.mean(y, axis=0)
    g = Model.x_mean - y_mean
    mah = g.T.dot(Model.inverse_pooled_covariance).dot(g) ** 0.5
    return mah

def generate_lut():
    levels = 256
    levels2 = levels**2
    lut = [0] * (levels ** 3)

    levels_range = range(0, levels)

    for r in levels_range:
        for g in levels_range:
            for b in levels_range:
                lut[r + (g * levels) + (b * levels2)] = rgb2something(r, g, b)

    return lut

def calculate_distance(lut, input_image):
    return np.take(lut, input_image[:, :, 0] + (input_image[:, :, 1] * 256) + (input_image[:, :, 2] * 65536))

lut = generate_lut()
rgb = np.random.randint(255, size=(1080, 1920, 3), dtype=np.uint8)
result = calculate_distance(lut, rgb)

cv2.imshow("Example", rgb)
cv2.imshow("Result", result)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Comment: Have you tried numpy vectorise with combinations ?

Comment: What does `rgb2something` look like? | Yeah, generating and using a 64 or 128 MB lookup table won't be very efficient (the generation is 2^24 iterations in Python -- interpreter is slow -- and the huge lookup won't be very cache friendly). A vectorized approach (with nice, predictable access pattern) would be much better, as the above comment mentions.

Comment: @NiteyaShah I have not, I've never had experience with that before, could you provide an example?

Comment: @DanMašek I've added an example of what the function might look like, could you provide an example of what the vecorised pattern would look like? By access pattern do you mean like a 1D array?

Comment: Cool, I'll have a look at it. Ya, I mean the memory access pattern, the memory being linear. It's best to read the memory in sequence (or with small steps) due to how CPU+caches work -- it ensures that most of the time the data you need is very close to the CPU. On the other hand, when you access a very large chunk of memory in random pattern, there's very high probability that the data you need is only in the main memory... which usually costs something like 100-150 clock cycles to fetch.

Comment: BTW, what's `Consts`? Could you, please provide a full [mcve], so we can reproduce the issue?

Comment: @RaymondTunstill why don't you make a dictionary (essentially a hash table) where you compute `rgb2something` for each `(r, g, b)` tuple when it is needed, and add it to the dictionary. This is simpler and more readable imo. Moreover, at runtime, you may end up computing `rgb2something` values for only a small subset of rgb values, instead of computing them for all rgb values as you're currently doing. Of course, this depends on your exact use case.

Comment: @RohanSaxena For a single small enough image (less than the 2^24 iterations where the LUT is generated), just running the calculations would be definitely faster... although still running in the interpreter, so relatively damn slow. Lazy initialized cache you mention could help somewhat in that case (perhaps a lot depending on the kind of the input). Still, there might be some potential to speed it up if we can use vectorized operation instead of looping in the interpeter.

Comment: Just a small nitpick re your working example: You should probably add a row to `x`, because as it stands the centered `x` will always be singular. (Centered means the column sums are all 0, in other words, the rows are not linearly independent. If there are only three rows the matrix must be rank deficient, in particular the cov matrix has no inverse.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Update: added blas optimization

There are several straightforward and very effective optimizations:

(1) vectorize, vectorize! It is not so difficult to vectorize essentially everything in this code. See below.

(2) use proper lookup, i.e fancy indexing, not `np.take`

(3) use Cholesky decomp. With blas `dtrmm` we can exploit its triangular structure

And here is the code. Just add it to the end of OP's code (under EDIT 2). Unless you are very patient you probably also want to comment out the `lut = generate_lut()` and `result = calculate_distance(lut, rgb)` lines and all references to cv2. I've also added a random row to `x` to make its covariance matrix non singular.

```
class Full_Model(Model):
    ch = np.linalg.cholesky(Model.inverse_pooled_covariance)
    chx = Model.x_mean@ch

def rgb2something_vectorized(rgb):
    return np.sqrt(np.sum(((rgb - Full_Model.x_mean)@Full_Model.ch)**2,  axis=-1))

from scipy.linalg import blas

def rgb2something_blas(rgb):
    *shp, nchan = rgb.shape
    return np.sqrt(np.einsum('...i,...i', *2*(blas.dtrmm(1, Full_Model.ch.T, rgb.reshape(-1, nchan).T, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0).T - Full_Model.chx,))).reshape(shp)

def generate_lut_vectorized():
    return rgb2something_vectorized(np.transpose(np.indices((256, 256, 256))))

def generate_lut_blas():
    rng = np.arange(256)
    arr = np.empty((256, 256, 256, 3))
    arr[0, ..., 0]  = rng
    arr[0, ..., 1]  = rng[:, None]
    arr[1:, ...] = arr[0]
    arr[..., 2] = rng[:, None, None]
    return rgb2something_blas(arr)

def calculate_distance_vectorized(lut, input_image):
    return lut[input_image[..., 2], input_image[..., 1], input_image[..., 0]]

# test code

def random_check_lut(lut):
    """Because the original lut generator is excruciatingly slow,
    we only compare a random sample, using the original code
    """
    levels = 256
    levels2 = levels**2
    lut = lut.ravel()

    levels_range = range(0, levels)

    for r, g, b in np.random.randint(0, 256, (1000, 3)):
        assert np.isclose(lut[r + (g * levels) + (b * levels2)], rgb2something(r, g, b))

import time
td = []
td.append((time.time(), 'create lut vectorized'))
lutv = generate_lut_vectorized()
td.append((time.time(), 'create lut using blas'))
lutb = generate_lut_blas()
td.append((time.time(), 'lookup using np.take'))
res = calculate_distance(lutv, rgb)
td.append((time.time(), 'process on the fly (no lookup)'))
resotf = rgb2something_vectorized(rgb)
td.append((time.time(), 'process on the fly (blas)'))
resbla = rgb2something_blas(rgb)
td.append((time.time(), 'lookup using fancy indexing'))
resv = calculate_distance_vectorized(lutv, rgb)
td.append((time.time(), None))

print("sanity checks ... ", end='')
assert np.allclose(res, resotf) and np.allclose(res, resv) \
    and np.allclose(res, resbla) and np.allclose(lutv, lutb)
random_check_lut(lutv)
print('all ok\n')

t, d = zip(*td)
for ti, di in zip(np.diff(t), d):
    print(f'{di:32s} {ti:10.3f} seconds')
```

Sample run:

```
sanity checks ... all ok

create lut vectorized                 1.116 seconds
create lut using blas                 0.917 seconds
lookup using np.take                  0.398 seconds
process on the fly (no lookup)        0.127 seconds
process on the fly (blas)             0.069 seconds
lookup using fancy indexing           0.064 seconds
```

We can see that the best lookup beats the best on-the-fly computation by a whisker. That said the example may overestimate lookup cost, because random pixels are presumably less cache friendly than natural images.

### Original answer (perhaps still useful to some)

If rgb2something can't be vectorized, and you want to process one typical image, then you can get a decent speedup using `np.unique`.

If rgb2something is expensive and multiple images have to be processed, then `unique` can be combined with caching, which is conveniently done using `functools.lru_cache`---only (minor) stumbling block: arguments must be hashable. As it turns out the modification in code that this forces (casting rgb-arrays to 3-byte strings) happens to benefit performance.

Using a full look up table is only worth it if you have a huge number of pixels covering most hues. In that case the fastest way is using numpy fancy indexing to do the actual lookup.

```
import numpy as np
import time
import functools

def rgb2something(rgb):
    # waste some time:
    np.exp(0.1*rgb)
    return rgb.mean()

@functools.lru_cache(None)
def rgb2something_lru(rgb):
    rgb = np.frombuffer(rgb, np.uint8)
    # waste some time:
    np.exp(0.1*rgb)
    return rgb.mean()

def apply_to_img(img):
    shp = img.shape
    return np.reshape([rgb2something(x) for x in img.reshape(-1, shp[-1])], shp[:2])

def apply_to_img_lru(img):
    shp = img.shape
    return np.reshape([rgb2something_lru(x) for x in img.ravel().view('S3')], shp[:2])

def apply_to_img_smart(img, print_stats=True):
    shp = img.shape
    unq, bck = np.unique(img.reshape(-1, shp[-1]), return_inverse=True, axis=0)
    if print_stats:
        print('total no pixels', shp[0]*shp[1], '\nno unique pixels', len(unq))
    return np.array([rgb2something(x) for x in unq])[bck].reshape(shp[:2])

def apply_to_img_smarter(img, print_stats=True):
    shp = img.shape
    unq, bck = np.unique(img.ravel().view('S3'), return_inverse=True)
    if print_stats:
        print('total no pixels', shp[0]*shp[1], '\nno unique pixels', len(unq))
    return np.array([rgb2something_lru(x) for x in unq])[bck].reshape(shp[:2])

def make_full_lut():
    x = np.empty((3,), np.uint8)
    return np.reshape([rgb2something(x) for x[0] in range(256)
                       for x[1] in range(256) for x[2] in range(256)],
                      (256, 256, 256))

def make_full_lut_cheat(): # for quicker testing lookup
    i, j, k = np.ogrid[:256, :256, :256]
    return (i + j + k) / 3

def apply_to_img_full_lut(img, lut):
    return lut[(*np.moveaxis(img, 2, 0),)]

from scipy.misc import face

t0 = time.perf_counter()
bw = apply_to_img(face())
t1 = time.perf_counter()
print('naive                 ', t1-t0, 'seconds')

t0 = time.perf_counter()
bw = apply_to_img_lru(face())
t1 = time.perf_counter()
print('lru first time        ', t1-t0, 'seconds')

t0 = time.perf_counter()
bw = apply_to_img_lru(face())
t1 = time.perf_counter()
print('lru second time       ', t1-t0, 'seconds')

t0 = time.perf_counter()
bw = apply_to_img_smart(face(), False)
t1 = time.perf_counter()
print('using unique:         ', t1-t0, 'seconds')

rgb2something_lru.cache_clear()

t0 = time.perf_counter()
bw = apply_to_img_smarter(face(), False)
t1 = time.perf_counter()
print('unique and lru first: ', t1-t0, 'seconds')

t0 = time.perf_counter()
bw = apply_to_img_smarter(face(), False)
t1 = time.perf_counter()
print('unique and lru second:', t1-t0, 'seconds')

t0 = time.perf_counter()
lut = make_full_lut_cheat()
t1 = time.perf_counter()
print('creating full lut:    ', t1-t0, 'seconds')

t0 = time.perf_counter()
bw = apply_to_img_full_lut(face(), lut)
t1 = time.perf_counter()
print('using full lut:       ', t1-t0, 'seconds')

print()
apply_to_img_smart(face())

import Image
Image.fromarray(bw.astype(np.uint8)).save('bw.png')
```

Sample run:

```
naive                  6.8886632949870545 seconds
lru first time         1.7458112589956727 seconds
lru second time        0.4085628940083552 seconds
using unique:          2.0951434450107627 seconds
unique and lru first:  2.0168916099937633 seconds
unique and lru second: 0.3118703299842309 seconds
creating full lut:     151.17599205300212 seconds
using full lut:        0.12164952099556103 seconds

total no pixels 786432 
no unique pixels 134105
```

Comment: Thank you for your tests, however, it's already known that the full LUT is faster, the question is how to optimize this problem by creating either a smaller LUT or a faster access pattern for a larger LUT. Since this will be in a real-time system a large range of hues is probable.

Comment: @RaymondTunstill "_it's already known that the full LUT is faster_". Well, to you maybe, but you only now shared some critical bits of information. Anyway, I suspect you will find the updated answer interesting.

Comment: How can I use this given a .cube or a .3dl LUT file?

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, please add what `Consts` is in your `rgb2something` function, as that will help us understand what exactly the function does.

The best way to speed this up would be to vectorize the operation.

## 1) No caching

You don't *need* to construct a lookup table for this operation. If you have a function that is applied on each `(r, g, b)` vector, you can simply apply it for every vector in the image using `np.apply_along_axis`. In the following example, I'm assuming a simple definition for `rgb2something` as a placeholder - this function can of course be replaced by your definition.

```
def rgb2something(vector):
    return sum(vector)

image = np.random.randint(0, 256, size=(100, 100, 3), dtype=np.uint8)
transform = np.apply_along_axis(rgb2something, -1, image)
```

This takes the `image` array, and applies the function `rgb2something` to each 1-D slice along axis `-1` (which is the last channel axis).

## 2) Lazily filled lookup table

While caching is not necessary, there may be specific use cases when it will benefit you greatly. Perhaps you want to perform this pixel-wise operation of `rgb2something` across thousands of images, and you suspect that many pixel values will be repeated across images. In such cases, constructing a lookup table could significantly improve performance. I'd suggest lazily filling up the table (I suggest this presuming that your dataset spans images which are somewhat similar - having similar objects, textures and so on, which would mean that in total they span only a relatively small subset of the whole 2^24 search space). If you feel that they span a relatively large subset, you could construct the entire lookup table beforehand (see next section).

```
lut = [-1] * (256 ** 3)

def actual_rgb2something(vector):
    return sum(vector)

def rgb2something(vector):
    value = lut[vector[0] + vector[1] * 256 + vector[2] * 65536]

    if value == -1:
        value = actual_rgb2something(vector)
        lut[vector[0] + vector[1] * 256 + vector[2] * 65536] = value

    return value
```

You can then transform each image same as before:

```
image = np.random.randint(0, 256, size=(100, 100, 3), dtype=np.uint8)
transform = np.apply_along_axis(rgb2something, -1, image)
```

## 3) Precomputed cache

Perhaps your images are diverse enough to encompass a large set of the entire search range, and the cost of construction of the entire cache can be amortized by the reduced lookup cost.

```
from itertools import product

lut = [-1] * (256 ** 3)

def actual_rgb2something(vector):
    return sum(vector)

def fill(vector):
    value = actual_rgb2something(vector)
    lut[vector[0] + vector[1] * 256 + vector[2] * 65536] = value

# Fill the table
total = list(product(range(256), repeat=3))
np.apply_along_axis(fill, arr=total, axis=1)
```

Now instead of computing the values again, you can simply look them up from the table:

```
def rgb2something(vector):
    return lut[vector[0] + vector[1] * 256 + vector[2] * 65536]
```

Transforming images is of course the same as before:

```
image = np.random.randint(0, 256, size=(100, 100, 3), dtype=np.uint8)
transform = np.apply_along_axis(rgb2something, -1, image)
```

Comment: I believe the op wants to improve his per image performance rather than for every image

Comment: Also his code works for every RGB vector combination possible and not just along the RGB vector of the image , ie you have locked your operation along an axis while he is running a for loop along all 3 of his axis

Comment: I have added another edit with a full code example, which I hope clears up exactly what Consts was. Just a static class member representing a model, and rgb2something compares each pixel to that model. Thank you for your answer I will look at what performance increase I get with the lazy approach, however, the use case is real-time image processing at around 40 frames a second so the data range will be large.

Comment: @NiteyaShah as for your first question, I just stated the use case of multiple images in a dataset as an example, as I got the feeling the op wanted to process multiple images in a pipeline (indeed, this is what he does intend to do as per his last comment on this thread). But I still suggested different techniques which may be better in different use cases.

Comment: @NiteyaShah For your second remark: In the cached version (particularly in the precomputed cache), I compute the values for every possible pixel. Please see section (3) of the answer again.