# Map colors in image to closest member of a list of colors, in Python

Tags: python, numpy, indexing, colors, rgb

I have a list of 19 colors, which is a numpy array of size `(19,3)`:

```
colors = np.array([[0, 0, 0], 
[0, 0, 255], 
[255, 0, 0], 
[150, 30, 150], 
[255, 65, 255], 
[150, 80, 0], 
[170, 120, 65], 
[125, 125, 125], 
[255, 255, 0], 
[0, 255, 255], 
[255, 150, 0], 
[255, 225, 120], 
[255, 125, 125], 
[200, 100, 100], 
[0, 255, 0], 
[0, 150, 80], 
[215, 175, 125], 
[220, 180, 210], 
[125, 125, 255]
])
```

Now I have an image (numpy array of size `(1024,1024,3)`), with colors that are somewhat close or equal to all of the colors defined above. However, my program requires that the image can only contain the colors above and not a closeby color, so I need to convert the color of each pixel in the array to the closest color of the 19 colors.

I saw a function to find the closest color from a set of colors that uses only Numpy (which works perfectly) here [Python - Find the closest color to a color, from giving list of colors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54242194/python-find-the-closest-color-to-a-color-from-giving-list-of-colors):

```
def closest_color(colors,color):
    colors = np.array(colors)
    color = np.array(color)
    distances = np.sqrt(np.sum((colors-color)**2,axis=1))
    index_of_smallest = np.where(distances==np.amin(distances))
    smallest_distance = colors[index_of_smallest]
return smallest_distance
```

With this function I can find the closest color to a single color from a predefined list, but in my problem I do not have a single color that I would like to change but a whole image (1024 x 1024 pixels of colors). What is the most efficient way to leverage this function (or using any better function) that uses numpy only to solve my problem. I would like to reduce the amount of for loops as much as possible, since I need process 30,000 images of size 1024 x 1024 in total.

Thanks!

Comment: "closest colour" isn't really a well defined. What is the end goal? Closest for a computer in RGB using 1-norm of 2-norm? Or should you weight the channels differently? Or do you mean closest for a human viewing it with human eyes? If the latter, you are almost certainly going to want to work a different colour space, i.e. not RBG. If it's just the look of the thing, then HSV might be ok. If it's mapping to an intensity value that you want human's to be able to compare, then maybe [HCL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HCL_color_space).

Comment: Don't forget to declare your colors array as dtype='uint8', otherwise the cKDTree will return a float type with (potentially) incorrect quantization.

Comment: Wikipedia [Color_quantization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_quantization) has a nice picture of a 16-color cat. See also [Color_difference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_difference) and [colorspacious](https://colorspacious.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial.html#color-similarity).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We can use [`Cython-powered kd-tree` for quick nearest-neighbor lookup](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.cKDTree.query.html) and hence achieve our classification/bucketing -

```
from scipy.spatial import cKDTree

# Input image : img
out_img = colors[cKDTree(colors).query(img,k=1)[1]]
```

Comment: How to save ```out_img``` as an image?

Comment: @MichaelJulyusChristopherM. `out_img` is a 2D array of colors. Not sure  what you mean by saving it. For saving an array, use - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/902761/saving-a-numpy-array-as-an-image

Comment: This didn't work for me until I applied `cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)` first. After that it worked fantastic and it's blazing fast.

Comment: @Divakar What are you using for the color variable? I'm getting "only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index" as error when using an array.

Comment: @MichaelJulyusChristopherM. `Image.fromarray(out_img.astype(np.uint8)).save('out.png')`

Answer (score 4):

The question not only asks for finding the nearest neighbor - which the other answers provide - but how to efficiently apply the exchange over 30000 images.

Performance improvement:

Instead of computing the distance per pixel per image (30000*1024*1024 = 31457280000), compute a mapping once for each possible color onto your palette.

Then use that mapping to exchange the pixels.

```
import numpy as np
import itertools as it
import scipy.spatial.distance

palette  = np.array([[0, 0, 0], 
[0, 0, 255], 
[255, 0, 0], 
[150, 30, 150], 
[255, 65, 255], 
[150, 80, 0], 
[170, 120, 65], 
[125, 125, 125], 
[255, 255, 0], 
[0, 255, 255], 
[255, 150, 0], 
[255, 225, 120], 
[255, 125, 125], 
[200, 100, 100], 
[0, 255, 0], 
[0, 150, 80], 
[215, 175, 125], 
[220, 180, 210], 
[125, 125, 255]
])

valueRange = np.arange(0,256)
allColors = np.array(list(it.product(valueRange,valueRange,valueRange)))
mapping = scipy.spatial.distance.cdist(allColors, palette).argmin(1)
```

In addition I recommend the lecture of [Creating fast RGB look up tables in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52486840/creating-fast-rgb-look-up-tables-in-python)

Answer (score 1):

Since what you are calculating is the Euclidean distance, you can compute every pair of distances quickly with [`scipy.spatial.distance.cdist`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.cdist.html), then pick the closest color from the resulting distance matrix:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.spatial.distance

np.random.seed(0)
palette = np.array([
    [0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 255],
    [255, 0, 0],
    [150, 30, 150],
    [255, 65, 255],
    [150, 80, 0],
    [170, 120, 65],
    [125, 125, 125],
    [255, 255, 0],
    [0, 255, 255],
    [255, 150, 0],
    [255, 225, 120],
    [255, 125, 125],
    [200, 100, 100],
    [0, 255, 0],
    [0, 150, 80],
    [215, 175, 125],
    [220, 180, 210],
    [125, 125, 255]
])
data = np.random.randint(256, size=(10, 3))
closest_idx = scipy.spatial.distance.cdist(data, palette).argmin(1)
data_in_palette = palette[closest_idx]
print(*zip(data, data_in_palette), sep='\n')
# (array([172,  47, 117]), array([150,  30, 150]))
# (array([192,  67, 251]), array([255,  65, 255]))
# (array([195, 103,   9]), array([150,  80,   0]))
# (array([211,  21, 242]), array([255,  65, 255]))
# (array([36, 87, 70]), array([  0, 150,  80]))
# (array([216,  88, 140]), array([200, 100, 100]))
# (array([ 58, 193, 230]), array([  0, 255, 255]))
# (array([ 39,  87, 174]), array([125, 125, 125]))
# (array([ 88,  81, 165]), array([125, 125, 125]))
# (array([25, 77, 72]), array([  0, 150,  80]))
```