# Python fast color comparison numpy vectorize , cKDTree

Tags: python, numpy, colors

**I have a function to lookup the closest color in a lab palette and return a value of 1 of 12 values for a paletted image.**
Images are up to 1000x1000 pixels .
There is a dataframe with some color values. Now 500 of them will be up to 2000.

[image]

```
from skimage.io import imread
from skimage.color import rgb2lab, deltaE_ciede2000, lab2rgb

im = imread('test.jpg')[:,:,:3] # read image

im1 = color.rgb2lab(im) # convert to Lab

arr_lab = dfxl[['L*','a*','b*']].to_numpy()   # array of lab values from DF
arr_12col = dfxl[['maxR','maxG','maxB']].to_numpy()   # array of palette colors from DF


# palette party ( image vectorized )
distance = np.linalg.norm(im1[:,:,None] - arr_lab[None,None,:], axis=3) # distance matrix
pal_img = np.argmin(distance, axis=2)   # index of closest colors
out_img1 = arr_12col[pal_img]   # convert to 1 of 12 palette colors
Image.fromarray(out_img1.astype(np.uint8)).save('out_test.png')   # save


# palette party 2 ( image cKDTree)
# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57496971
from scipy.spatial import cKDTree
out_img = arr_12col[cKDTree(arr_lab).query(im1,k=1)[1]]


# palette party 3 ( single color check)
dists = deltaE_ciede2000(lab_values, np.array([lab_color]) , channel_axis=1)
closest_color = (dists.argmin())
```

The first solution is quite fast but gets slow with big images. **Does not always return perceptual closest color**.

The second solution (from SO questions/57496971) is super fast, but same **problem with quality**.

The third solution is only manual but **delivers the best perceptual closest color.**

Is there a way to **vectorize the deltaE-ciede2000** cause looping is no alternative or can the cKDTree be built with deltaE values ?

Comment: Glancing through the source code, it looks like `deltaE_ciede2000` is already vectorized. If that doesn't work, please update the question with the code you tried and full tracebacks for any errors.

Comment: The deltaE_ciede2000 is only used to check a single color (lab_color). Works fine. I wonder how to pass a comlete image (all xy pixel values) and rebuild the image. The deltaE_ciede2000 is quite complex, so I guess if this isnt pure optimized numpy it will get slow ?

Comment: The implementation in scikit-image is already pure vectorized numpy, so you can just pass the whole image in at once, much like in the first solution.